# How do I calculate the area 1.5cm away from a LED with a 120 degree beam?

Tags: led, infrared, calculation

I have a SMD2835 IR LED with dimensions of 0.28cm X 0.35cm and beam angle of 120 degrees.

How do I calculate the irradiation area if it is e.g 1.5cm away?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably good method is to convert the LED area to a square i.e. 0.28 mm x 0.35 mm becomes a square of 0.31 mm x 0.31 mm. Then project back to a vanishing point that has to form a triangle with the 0.31 mm dimension at 120 degrees.

That gives you a distance that can be used in the final calculation. i.e. if the distance to the vanishing point from the LED is 0.2 mm then you know that the distance to a more distant surface (15 mm distant) is 15.2 mm to the vanishing point.

Take the ratios of the distances and square the result to find the ratio of areas. Then multiply by 0.31 sq mm to find the actual area. It's going to be about 2000 sq mm from my rough brain calcs.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the irradiation area of the SMD2835 IR LED at a distance of 1.5 cm, you can use trigonometry. Given the beam angle of \$x^\circ\$, you can consider the irradiation area as a circular segment. Here's how you can calculate it:

Calculate the radius of the circular segment. Since the beam angle is \$x^\circ\$ degrees, it cuts out one-third of the entire circle. So, the central angle of the circular segment is \$\displaystyle\frac{x}{2}\$ degrees.

The radius \$\text{r}\$ of the circular segment can be calculated using the formula:

$$\text{r}=\text{d}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\theta\$ is the central angle in radians (\$\frac{x}{2}\$ degrees converted to radians).

Calculate the area of the circular segment. The area of a circular segment can be calculated using the formula:

$$\text{A}=\frac{\text{r}^2}{2}\cdot\left(\theta-\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\tag2$$

Using these formulas, you can calculate the irradiation area of the IR LED at a distance of 1.5 cm. Because we get:

$$\text{A}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\text{d}\cdot\tan\left(\theta\right)\right)^2\cdot\left(\theta-\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\tag3$$

Using your values, we find:

$$\text{A}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{200}\cdot\sqrt{3}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\tag4$$